# ActionScript 3 and mxml

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

My problem is this:
I want to use mxml for visual element... i want to graphically set components and in an as class to program because it easy to me... How to do this??? I have two classes: one as and one mxml...This is my code:

```
public class chat extends Application{
    private var nc:NetConnection = null;
    public var connect:Button;      
    public var status:Text;

    public function VideoChat(){
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, mainInit);
    }

    private function mainInit(event:FlexEvent):void{            
        status.text = "Status quo";

        connect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);
    }
```

and mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" backgroundColor="#FBF8F8"
           preloaderChromeColor="#CC3535" 
           >

    <mx:Button x="77" y="547" height="19" label="Connect" id="connect"/>
    <mx:UIComponent id="videoReceiveContainer" x="77" y="52" width="500" height="400"/>
    <mx:Button x="507" y="547" label="Play" id="play"/>
    <mx:Text id="status" x="77" y="460" width="501" height="58"/>
    <mx:Button x="297" y="547" label="Publish" id="publish"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: What is the **problem**? What is **not working** or **not understood**?

Comment: is this okey code??? Because when i run it it just plays blank page...

Comment: For me it shows the three defined buttons, nothing else. What do you **expect** it to show?

Comment: For me it's just a blank page...it need's to show three buttons and a video container after that...but you dont have a code here for that...how did you run it??? Run click on project, run as and web app???

Comment: and what path is in your browser??? is it bin-debug/name.mxml???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your AS3 code is a liiiittle bit funky.

```
public class VideoChat extends Application{
    private var nc:NetConnection = null;
    public var connect:Button;      
    public var status:Text;

    public function VideoChat(){
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, mainInit);
    }

    private function mainInit(event:FlexEvent):void{            
        status.text = "Status quo";

        connect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);
    }
}
```

The name of the class has to match the name of the constructor.

Second, the MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<local:VideoChat xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                 xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                 xmlns:local="*"
                 minWidth="955" minHeight="600" backgroundColor="#FBF8F8"
                 preloaderChromeColor="#CC3535" 
                 >

    <mx:Button x="77" y="547" height="19" label="Connect" id="connect"/>
    <mx:UIComponent id="videoReceiveContainer" x="77" y="52" width="500" height="400"/>
    <mx:Button x="507" y="547" label="Play" id="play"/>
    <mx:Text id="status" x="77" y="460" width="501" height="58"/>
    <mx:Button x="297" y="547" label="Publish" id="publish"/>
</local:VideoChat>
```

If you notice, I defined the XML namespace 'local' `xmlns:local="*"`. And the `s:Application` tag has been replaced with `local:VideoChat`.

Lastly, you asked in a comment what the path was to load the page. It should be `...bin-debug/name.html`. This HTML file is a wrapper that displays the compiled SWF of your project.

Comment: Now i have an error:Unable to locate specified base class 'VideoChat' for component class 'fm.domain.H264'. Any idea???

Comment: And when i do like you recomended here, in mxml file, on outline i do not have containers...just in red color !Root ....maybe this is the problem...

Comment: @Jovan Your first error is related to code that I have not seen, so I can't say. Also, I don't understand what you mean about containers.

Comment: For some reason package is a problem...I started all over again and this time i did like you said here and all worked... Thanks Sam..